# Save form data on GET requests in Spring MVC

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, get, textarea, javabeans

I have this huge **spring form** containing a table where the user can add or delete rows of data. It is basically a GridView. For deleting I have put anchors which do the job through **GET requests**. The problem I am facing is that after a user has added one or more rows of data to the table, which are still in editable (textarea) mode, if he wants to delete some other row, the text that he has painstakingly written on those textareas dissappear, they do not get bound the **form bean** and they do not travel with the GET requests. I know not of an elegant solution to tackle the problem, except, ofcourse that I can submit the form periodically through Javascript. Is there a better design solution out there? Please share?

Comment: You are building something that drastically breaks with standard and convention.  You should seriously consider using the proper request method or, at the very least, something other than `GET`.  Reference: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Answer (score 2):

> For deleting I have put anchors which do the job through GET
>   requests.

A bad idea. Actually a very bad idea, a web crawler bot could delete rows accidently.

With a post request you simply have to ensure the name of the client side added element is congruent (I assume it is a collection on a backing bean) with the existing spring form.

Comment: Really a bad idea, I never thought of the bots. Though our application is internal to our organisation, still this is not a good design. Can you elaborate on how I can use POST to delete the element. i have to use buttons instead of anchors. How can I know at the server side that which button has been clicked. I am new at Spring. Yes it is a collection on a backing bean.

Comment: submit a form, have different forms for different buttons. Make the button alter which data is sent to server, or which url the form is mapped to. There is also a request method of DELETE if you want to stay strictly restful.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can carry on from here.